# After adding an entry to the tree, it is not displayed. Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

The application displays the tree.
Records are added using the 'rowediting' plugins.

In the controller, by clicking on the "Create" button, an event is triggered.

```
...
onAddChild: function(el) {
        var grid = el.up('treepanel'),
            sel = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0],
            store = grid.getStore();


        store.suspendAutoSync()
        var child = sel.appendChild({
            text: '',
            leaf: true
        });    
       sel.expand()
        grid.getView().editingPlugin.startEdit(child);
        store.resumeAutoSync();

    },
...
```

The plugin itself looks like this:

```
plugins: [{
        ptype: 'rowediting',
        clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
        autoCancel: false,
        listeners: {
            afteredit: function (editor, context, eOpts) {
                context.store.reload();

            },
            canceledit: function (editor, context, eOpts) {
                context.store.reload();
            },
            beforeedit: function (editor, context) {
                return !context.record.isRoot();
            }
        }
    }],
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('Survey.store.QuestionTreeStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    model: 'Survey.model.QuestionTree',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    //storeId: 'QuestionTree',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        noCache: false,
        api: {
            create:     urlRoot + 'Create',
            update:     urlRoot + 'Update',
            destroy:    urlRoot + 'Destroy',
            read:       urlRoot + 'Read'
        },
```

The problem is that adding a record happens, but at the same time it is not displayed in the tree, I need to refresh the page so that the record would appear.
How to make a new entry immediately appear in the tree?

Thank